# R list - combine elements with same name

Tags: r, list

I have a list in R:

```
A = list(c(1,4), 2, 3, c(1,4))

names(A) <- c("name 1", "name 2", "name 2", "name 3")

$`name 1`
[1] 1 4

$`name 2`
[1] 2

$`name 2`
[1] 3

$`name 3`
[1] 1 4
```

I want to combine the list elements with the same name. Output would look like this

```
$`name 1`
[1] 1 4

$`name 2`
[1] 2 3

$`name 3`
[1] 1 4
```

How would I achieve this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An option would be to use `names` as a grouping variable after `unlist`ing the `list` and use it in `tapply` to concatenate the elements that belong to the same group

```
tapply(unlist(A, use.names = FALSE), rep(names(A), lengths(A)), FUN = c)
#$`name 1`
#[1] 1 4

#$`name 2`
#[1] 2 3

#$`name 3`
#[1] 1 4
```

---

Or using `split`

```
split(unlist(A, use.names = FALSE), rep(names(A), lengths(A)))
```

Or a compact option with `stack` and `split`

```
with(stack(A), split(values, ind))
```

---

Or loop through the `unique` names of 'A', do a `==` to select the elements of 'A' that belong to the same `name`

```
lapply(unique(names(A)), function(x) unlist(A[x== names(A)], use.names = FALSE))
```

Comment: `tapply(unlist(b, use.names = TRUE, recursive=FALSE), rep(names(b), lengths(b)), FUN = c)?`seem to be the best output with this approach

Comment: sorry for the downvote, I think I clicked it by mistake, as I do not use downvotes normally ...
see this for lists of lists: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59789456/rlist-combine-elements-of-the-same-name-some-are-lists/59790117#59790117

Comment: Be careful when using this code and not copy/pasting: I used `length` instead of `lengths`, which will give different results when lists are not of equal length.

Comment: @Frederick `length` and `lengths` are completely different functions and its behavior is different