# Rlist, combine elements of the same name (some are lists)

Tags: r

I have a list where elements are list, I want to combine those with the same name, without loosing the structure of the others.
In other word, I want to transform this list2 into list1

```
list1= list ("credit" = list("Conceptualization", "Software"), ".attrs" = list ("contrib-type"= "author"))
list2 =list ("credit" = "Conceptualization","credit" ="Software", ".attrs" = list ("contrib-type"= "author"))
```

I tried to play with unlist and the answer I found here, but it destroys the .attrs element:

```
tapply(unlist(list2, use.names = FALSE, recursive=FALSE), rep(names(list2), lengths(list2)), FUN = list)

$.attrs
$.attrs[[1]]
[1] "author"


$credit
$credit[[1]]
[1] "Conceptualization"

$credit[[2]]
[1] "Software"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you only want the 1st level and it's not a list. I use `dplyr::lst` "Note that `lst` lifecycle's is questioning" because it supports `dplyr` quasiquotation.

```
sapply(unique(names(list2)), function(x) {
  #browser()
  if(sum(names(list2)==x)>=2 & !any(sapply(list2[names(list2)==x], function(l) is.list(l)))){
    item <- list2[names(list2)==x]
    names(item) <- NULL
    dplyr::lst(!!x := item)
  } else {
    list2[x]
  }

}, USE.NAMES = FALSE)

$credit
$credit[[1]]
[1] "Conceptualization"

$credit[[2]]
[1] "Software"


$.attrs
$.attrs$`contrib-type`
[1] "author"
```

Comment: thank you, it works! (and a good example of how far I am from a real developer)

Comment: @JulienColomb thanks for the nice words, we all been there just stay around.

Answer (score 0):

Almost!

```
split(unname(list2), names(list2))

split(list2, names(list2))
```